# The region of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n (x-1)^n}{(n^3+1)(3^n+1)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to find the region of convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n n (x-1)^n}{(n^3+1)(3^n+1)}.
$$
I know that, by the limit comparison test,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n (x-1)^n}{(n^3+1)(3^n+1)}
$$
converges if and only if
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)^n}{n^2 3^n}
$$
converges, and, by the Leibniz criterion,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (x-1)^n}{n^2 3^n}
$$
converges if $|x-1|\le 3$. But I do not know how the convergence of the original series follows from these two facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series check "Radius of convergence" here your $a_n=\frac{n(-1)^n}{\left(n^3+1\right)(3^n+1)}$. You just find $r=3$ but notice that your center here is $x_0=1$(and not $x_0=0$) so you demand $|x-1|<3$ and you check in the case $|x-1|=3$ if the series converges.

Comment: How to check if the series converges or diverges in the case $|x-1|=3$?

Comment: It is $x=4$ or $x=-2$.Prove that for $x=-2$ the series converges(and if this holds then for $x=4$ the series converges since if a series converges absolutely then the series converges).For $x=-2$ notice that $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/n^2 $$ is greater than you series so you can tell that your series converges.Now for $x=4$ notice that your series converges absolutely(since its the series of $x=-2$ that I proved you before that converges).So the series converges in both values of $x